# Why is 1401-01-01 a Saturday in Ruby but a Thursday in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime

In Ruby:

```
> require 'time'
=> true
> Date.new(1401, 1, 1).saturday?
=> true
```

With MySQL:

```
SELECT dayofweek('1401-01-01')
```

This returns `5` which is Thursday.

In the OSX Calendar, this is also a Thursday.

What is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Most probably due to how both extrapolate the current Gregorian calendar to the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that one of those environments is taking into account the change from the Julian calendar to the Gregorian calendar (at various times since the 16th century depending on place).

Using my Noda Time library, we can see which is which:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var julian = new LocalDate(1401, 1, 1, 
                                   CalendarSystem.GetJulianCalendar(4));
        var gregorian = new LocalDate(1401, 1, 1,
                                      CalendarSystem.GetGregorianCalendar(4));

        Console.WriteLine("Julian: {0}", julian.IsoDayOfWeek);
        Console.WriteLine("Gregorian: {1}", gregorian.IsoDayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Saturday
Thursday
```

So it looks like Ruby has taken the transition into account, but MySQL hasn't.

The big question is: which calendar system were *you* interested in? (In 1401 you *probably* want the Julian one - but if you have dates in the 16th century or later, it becomes trickier...)

Comment: Thanks! This is just something that I stumbled across and was curious about why it was happening. I was vaguely aware that there was some date tomfoolery if you go back a few centuries, but I didn't know why.

Comment: For what it's worth, both systems returned `1752-09-14 = Thursday` and `1752-09-02 = Saturday`.

Comment: @Dean: That's odd. The Monday/Saturday part was a screw-up on my part, but I'm really surprised by Ruby giving Saturday. Maybe they've put the Julian/Gregorian switch somewhere else. Odd.

Comment: It looks `1582-10-15` is the first day where they sync up (and `1582-10-05` to `1882-10-14` doesn't exist at all in Ruby).

Comment: @Dean: Aha - that makes sense as the earliest date when it was adopted - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar. Will edit my answer to indicate the difference in centuries, and remove the last bit.

Comment: PostgreSQL matches MySQL's behavior. [Their rationale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) says, "Date conventions before the 19th century make for interesting reading, but are not consistent enough to warrant coding into a date/time handler."